# Xcode: Image becomes filled with color on UIBarItem while scaling, function initeWithImage(UIImage)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

please, help me to find some solution to the following problem. IOS, Xcode.
I have UIBarItem component - the button that switches languages on the toolbar. The bar has function initeWithImage(UIImage). The problem is when i am trying to scale the image it becomes filled with color...The picture is too big for the toolbar. I have changed the size of the picture manually, but it looks ugly (i need scaling).

I have tried to solve the problem:
1. trough Scale
2. through Frame size
3. and variations of the two above :)

Some code:

```
    self initWithImage:image //
                                 style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered //UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:target
                                action:action
 UIImage *image;
  image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@“image.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

---

```
-(UIImage )imageWithImages:(UIImage )image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Please, help me with this. Quite simple but tricky task. I have already spent several hours with that... Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use initWithImage method.
If you want to display the exact image you should use initWithCustomView method.

For example:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];
```

You can scale down the image before setting it to the image view if you want to.